# how to change the existing path name in ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, versions

while installing the ubuntu 18.04 .I have set a **name** and i want to change the name again . I tried using bash.rc.I have changed **username** but i can't change **userpath**  while using the command **pwd**

Answer (score 0):

Just to confirm, you would like to change an account's *home directory*? If so, you can do it like this:

1. Open terminal
2. `cd /home`
3. `sudo mkdir {new directory}`
4. `sudo chown {account}:{group} {new directory}`
5. `sudo usermod -d /home/{new directory} {account}`

**Notes:**

- you cannot change the home directory for the account that is currently signed in
  ⇢ if you want to change your own account, you'll need to sign in as a different user that has `sudo` privileges
- existing data and folders will not be changed
- you'll probably want to create the default folders such as `~/Desktop`, `~/Downloads`, `~/Music`, etc. if you do not plan on copying the current home directory contents over

Hope this answers your question.

Comment: your are saying i need to add a new user

Comment: Nope. You need to add a new directory and assign it to an account. If you only have one account on the machine, then you may need to create one *temporarily* with sudo permissions so that you can perform Step 5.

Comment: that only i am asking i need to create a new user account